# Django - cannot resolve keyword into field

Tags: python, django

I created a model called `key`, which extends the User model with a Foreign Key called `public`. Here is the model:

```
class key(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

This works, but when i try to execute the following query:

```
User.objects.get(public=token)
```

I get the following error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'public' into field`. How can i execute this query on a Foreign Key? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: This is not an extension of `User`. It is a separate model. If it were an extension (subclass), your query would probably have achieved what you want in the form `key.objects.get(public=token)`. (Django has mechanisms for using a subclass of its built-in user model.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a field of the `User` model. You can however use double underscores (`__`) to look through a relation, so you can query with:

```
User.objects.get(key__public=token)
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`key`</s> to `Key`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I just noticed that another way to do it could be to add a related_query_name on my model

Comment: @Jack022: yes if you do not like the name of the relation for *queries* in reverse, you can specify `related_query_name='otherkey'` for example in the `ForeignKey`, and then query with `.get(otherkey__public=token)`.